# How to manipulate the contents of an audio tag and create derivative audio tags from it?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

On my webpage, I have an audio file inside of an  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<audio src="myTrack.mp3" controls preload="auto"></audio>

</html>
```

I want to chop up this file stored in an  tag into multiple 10 second audio files that I could then insert into the webpage as their own audio files in seperate `<audio>` tags.
*Is it possible to do this in javascript?*

Comment: 1st items of business:  does the audio file come from your site?

Comment: It comes from my site :)

Comment: i'd suggest something like http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/rQv5h/light/ rather than creating different files. since audio files use config headers, it would be difficult to split the file up and wind up with valid segments. it might be possible using an ajax Blob response to send `xhr.response.slice(numStart, numStop)` to a `new FileReader()`, but it would be tricky...

Comment: @dandavis It isn't hard at all to split up an audio file, what are you talking about?  http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video  (Link says video, but audio is identical.)  And, what's this XHR nonsense?  The solution here is to split that audio up front if possible.  If it's not possible, then load that audio into something you can manage with the Web Audio API where you get full control over what is played and how it is played.

Comment: @Brad: we're talking about JS here though... ffmpeg is really slow to run from JS using emscripten, and other than that it's impossible. i agree that having different files before you get to JS would be easier, but that's not what the question was. WebAudio is a decent (if complex) option, but it doesn't have the widest compat. HXR would be the ideal way to get a binary image of the audio file into JS, where it can be processed by JS and the pieces then used by an <audio> tag or WebAudio API, or simply use the <audio> tag as linked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes, of course this is possible! :)**

- Make sure the audio fulfill CORS-requirements so we can load it with AJAX (loading from same origin as the page will of course fulfill this).
- Load the file as `ArrayBuffer` and decode it with `AudioContext`
- Calculate the number of segments and length of each (I use a time based length independent of channels below)
- Split the main buffer into smaller buffers
- Create a file-wrapper for the new buffer (below I made a simple WAVE wrapper for the demo)
- Feed that as Blob via an Object-URL to a new instance of the Audio element
- Keep keep track of the object-URLs so you can free them up when not needed anymore (`revokeObjectURL()`).

One drawback is of course that you would have to load the entire file into memory before processing it.

## Example

Hopefully the file I'm using for the demo will be available through the current CDN that is used to allow CORS usage (I own the copyright, feel free to use it for testing, but only testing!! :) ). The loading and decoding can take some time depending on your system and connection, so please be patient...

Ideally you should use an asynchronous approach splitting the buffers, but the demo targets only the needed steps to make the buffer segments available as new file fragments.

Also note that I did not take into consideration the last segment to be shorter than the others (I use floor, you should use ceil for the segment count and cut the last block length short). I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

```js
var actx = new(AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)(),
    url = "//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7ttdz6xsoaqbzdl/war_demo.mp3";

// STEP 1: Load audio file using AJAX ----------------------------------
fetch(url).then(function(resp) {return resp.arrayBuffer()}).then(decode);

// STEP 2: Decode the audio file ---------------------------------------
function decode(buffer) {
  actx.decodeAudioData(buffer, split);
}

// STEP 3: Split the buffer --------------------------------------------
function split(abuffer) {

  // calc number of segments and segment length
  var channels = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
      duration = abuffer.duration,
      rate = abuffer.sampleRate,
      segmentLen = 10,
      count = Math.floor(duration / segmentLen),
      offset = 0,
      block = 10 * rate;

  while(count--) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, block));
    var audio = new Audio(url);
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.volume = 0.75;
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    offset += block;
  }  
}

// Convert a audio-buffer segment to a Blob using WAVE representation
function bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, len) {

  var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
      length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
      buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
      view = new DataView(buffer),
      channels = [], i, sample,
      pos = 0;

  // write WAVE header
  setUint32(0x46464952);                         // "RIFF"
  setUint32(length - 8);                         // file length - 8
  setUint32(0x45564157);                         // "WAVE"

  setUint32(0x20746d66);                         // "fmt " chunk
  setUint32(16);                                 // length = 16
  setUint16(1);                                  // PCM (uncompressed)
  setUint16(numOfChan);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
  setUint16(numOfChan * 2);                      // block-align
  setUint16(16);                                 // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

  setUint32(0x61746164);                         // "data" - chunk
  setUint32(length - pos - 4);                   // chunk length

  // write interleaved data
  for(i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
    channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

  while(pos < length) {
    for(i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {             // interleave channels
      sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
      sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767)|0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
      view.setInt16(pos, sample, true);          // update data chunk
      pos += 2;
    }
    offset++                                     // next source sample
  }

  // create Blob
  return new Blob([buffer], {type: "audio/wav"});

  function setUint16(data) {
    view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
    pos += 2;
  }

  function setUint32(data) {
    view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
    pos += 4;
  }
}
```

```css
audio {display:block;margin-bottom:1px}
```

Comment: I use this to post wav files to my server with myFormData.append("tempfilename", bufferToWave(myAudioBuffer, 0, myAudioBuffer.length / myAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels))

Comment: Despite this question is old it still shows up. I was experimenting with your code. Being obsessed with that saved audio is exactly what it was before, I compared the copy made with this code with the original file, by buffers channel data. I've found that, for negative values, it differs by 1 int16. The problem lies here: `sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767)|0;`. I replaced this line with `sample *= 32768` and now it seems to produce nice ideal copy. Also I've removed clamping (previous line), because channel data is already in [-1...1] range.