# Load sound (XMLHttpRequest) and show play controls (html5 audio player)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I need to add html5 web audio player (with controls on html page) for loaded mp3 song to browser. 
How a can do it?

```js
 function loadSound(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        // When loaded decode the data
        request.onload = function() {

            // decode the data
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
                // when the audio is decoded play the sound
                if (request.response) {
                    
                }
   
                playSound(buffer);
                
            }, onError);
        }
        request.send();
    }

loadSound("hello.mp3");

    function playSound(buffer) {
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
    }
```

Comment: So you need to be able to pick what song is playing, and control the song itself?

Comment: Or i need control only loaded sound.

Comment: Any reason why you want to load the file with xhr? I mean, you could use an Audio element to load and buffer and then convert that into source for analyzer etc. if that is what you're after (for playlist I would recommend the same as this allows buffering only the data needed). If xhr is required, see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584420/how-to-manipulate-the-contents-of-an-audio-tag-and-create-derivative-audio-tags/30045041#30045041) can help, just use one segment for the file.

Comment: I need show audio spectrum analyzer - http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example3.html   Specrum work correct on Chrome, Firefox and etc only with xhr (after loading).

Comment: K3N, thank you!!!! But i can't draw spectrum (from my example in a topic). I can't join audio play event from your example with draw spectrum in my example. Help please.

Comment: I almost finish my solution, but i have a problem with Bolb in FF and Opera, help me please here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348906/ff-and-opera-not-open-encoded-files-with-url-blob