# Use renderedBuffer as HTML5 Audio tag

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So I've used WebAudioAPI to create a music from code. I've used OfflineAudioContext to create a music and it's oncomplete event is similar to this:

```
function(e) {
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var song = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    song.buffer = e.renderedBuffer;
    song.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    song.start();
}
```

Which plays the sound. And it works. But I would like to instead store it as an `<audio>` element, because it's easier to play, loop, pause and stop, which I need to reuse the song.

Is it possible? I'm googling for days, but I can't find how!

The idea was to use `var song = new Audio()` and something to copy the `e.renderedBuffer` to it.

Comment: The method you found is, as far as I'm aware, the only way to do this.

Like you said, it's not particularly elegant – but at the same time, it's also kind of amazing that it's possible. You're essentially *making an audio file in the browser with JavaScript*, and that's pretty cool.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584420/how-to-manipulate-the-contents-of-an-audio-tag-and-create-derivative-audio-tags/30045041#30045041) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found this code floating around: http://codedbot.com/questions-/911767/web-audio-api-output . I've created a copy here too: http://pastebin.com/rE9a1PaX .

I've managed to use this code to create and store an audio on the fly, using all the function provided in this link.

```
offaudioctx.oncomplete = function(e) {
    var buffer   = e.renderedBuffer;
    var UintWave = createWaveFileData(buffer);
    var base64   = btoa(uint8ToString(UintWave));

    songsarr.push(document.createElement('audio'))
    songsarr[songsarr.length-1].src = "data:audio/wav;base64," + base64;
    console.log("completed!");
};
```

It's not pretty, but it works. I'm leaving everything here in case someone finds an easier way.