# How to save renderedBuffer as an audio file

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am using the web audio api's offlineAudioContext to render an audio file with a different playback speed. When I do this the altered audio is held in the renderedBuffer.

I am wondering how I can download the audio held in the renderedBuffer?

Here is my code:

```
// define online and offline audio context
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*40,44100);
source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
// define variables
var pre = document.querySelector('pre');
var myScript = document.querySelector('script');
var play = document.querySelector('.play');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source
function getData() {
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'sound.mp4', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
var audioData = request.response;
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
  myBuffer = buffer;
  source.buffer = myBuffer;
  source.playbackRate.value = 0.50;
  source.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
  source.start();
  //source.loop = true;
  offlineCtx.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer) {
    console.log('Rendering completed successfully');
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); 
    var song = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    song.buffer = renderedBuffer;
    song.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    play.onclick = function() {
      song.start();
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
      // Note: The promise should reject when startRendering is called a second time on an OfflineAudioContext
  });
});
}
request.send();
}
// Run getData to start the process off
getData();
// dump script to pre element
pre.innerHTML = myScript.innerHTML;
```

Comment: My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584420/how-to-manipulate-the-contents-of-an-audio-tag-and-create-derivative-audio-tags/30045041#30045041) may help. It shows how to convert a buffer into a wav file. Then convert it to blob or data-uri for download.

Comment: @K3N that actually really helps. I want to also change the playbackRate so that the file I download has an altered playbackRate. Do you know where I would insert that piece of code?